# Can't add OneDrive for Business account in my Lumia's OneDrive app

Tags: onedrive

Our company uses SharePoint Online and Lumia (Windows) phones. When we try to add our OneDrive for Business accounts in our phones, it gives an error about not recognizing the email address. With Android phones we can add the OneDrive for Business accounts on top of personal accounts easily without any problems.

We think this problem might be related to the fact that the Lumia's own Microsoft account uses the same (work) email we are using in SharePoint Online. Is there some kind of trick we have to do or is it just not possible to add OneDrive for Business accounts on top of the Lumia's MS account for now?

Thank you!

Comment: How are you adding the account in the OneDrive app?

Comment: By opening the menu and choosing the "Add account" option :-)

Comment: Ah, they've changed ther UI for adding secondary accounts since I last did it :(